# EXE's VERSION info not displaying in Properties dialog (Windows XP)

Tags: windows, properties, console, version, exe

I have built a Win32 console application using Visual Studio 6.0 in Windows XP. The EXE does have a VERSION resource. I can open the EXE and display the version information with Visual Studio or with other programs that read resources.

But, when I right-click on the EXE and ask for its Properties, no VERSION resource info is shown. Is that normal for a console application? All of my GUI applications show version info in Properties, no problem.

What am I missing here? Or is that some kind of Windows XP limitation? All suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not normal.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing with exe's built with .NetCF 3.5. Viewing properties on an XP machine doesn't show a Version tab. But if I open it using DotPeek, the version number is shown.